# How does Java's PreparedStatement work?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am planning to replace repeatedly executed Statement objects with `PreparedStatement` objects to improve performance. I am using arguments like the MySQL function `now()`, and string variables.

Most of the `PreparedStatement` queries I have seen contained constant values (like `10`, and strings like `"New York"`) as arguments used for the `?` in the queries. How would I go about using functions like `now()`, and variables as arguments? Is it necessary to use the `?`s in the queries instead of actual values? I am quite confounded.

Comment: Are you asking if you can use a String-valued function in place of a String literal?  Are you asking if you can use an int-valued function in place of a literal integer?  Can you provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have variables use the '?'

```
int temp = 75;
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE test SET num = ?, due = now() ");
pstmt.setInt(1, temp); 
pstmt.executeUpdate():
```

Produces an sql statment that looks like:

```
UPDATE test SET num = 75, due = now();
```

Comment: This is not correct for most database systems. Most database systems will prepare the query text, and then send the parameter values on execute. This will never produce a statement that literally contains the parameter value.

Answer (score 14):

If you have a variable that comes from user input, it's essential that you use the ? rather than concatenating the strings. Users might enter a string maliciously, and if you drop the string straight into SQL it can run a command you didn't intend.

I realise this one is overused, but it says it perfectly:

[image: Little Bobby Tables]

Comment: I believe, you mean SQL Injections.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use placeholders in a PreparedStatement. Something like:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select sysdate from dual");
```

would work just fine. However, you can't use a placeholder and then bind a function call to it. Something like this can't be used to call the sysdate function:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select ? from dual");
stmt.setSomethingOrOther(1, "sysdate");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling built in functions of your SQL server then use [PreparedStatement](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

If you are calling stored procedures that have been loaded onto your SQL server then use [CallableStatement](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).

Use question marks as placeholders for function/procedure parameters that you are passing and function return values you are receiving.

Answer (score -1):

I've developed a function that allows you to use named parameters in your SQL queries:

```
private PreparedStatement generatePreparedStatement(String query, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws DatabaseException
    {
        String paramKey = "";
        Object paramValue = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        Pattern paramRegex = null; 
        Matcher paramMatcher = null;
        int paramIndex = 1;

        try
        {
            //Create the condition
            paramRegex = Pattern.compile("(:[\\d\\w_-]+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
            paramMatcher = paramRegex.matcher(query);
            statement = this.m_Connection.prepareStatement(paramMatcher.replaceAll("?"),
                                ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, 
                                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);

            //Check if there are parameters
            paramMatcher = paramRegex.matcher(query);
            while (paramMatcher.find()) 
            {
                paramKey = paramMatcher.group().substring(1);
                if(parameters != null && parameters.containsKey(paramKey))
                {
                    //Add the parameter 
                    paramValue = parameters.get(paramKey);
                    if (paramValue instanceof Date) 
                    {
                        statement.setDate(paramIndex, (java.sql.Date)paramValue);                 
                    } 
                    else if (paramValue instanceof Double) 
                    {
                        statement.setDouble(paramIndex, (Double)paramValue);                  
                    } 
                    else if (paramValue instanceof Long) 
                    {
                        statement.setLong(paramIndex, (Long)paramValue);                  
                    } 
                    else if (paramValue instanceof Integer) 
                    {
                        statement.setInt(paramIndex, (Integer)paramValue);                
                    } 
                    else if (paramValue instanceof Boolean) 
                    {
                        statement.setBoolean(paramIndex, (Boolean)paramValue);                
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        statement.setString(paramIndex, paramValue.toString());     
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new DatabaseException("The parameter '" + paramKey + "' doesn't exists in the filter '" + query + "'");
                }

                paramIndex++;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException  l_ex) 
        {
            throw new DatabaseException(tag.lib.common.ExceptionUtils.getFullMessage(l_ex));
        }

        return statement;
    }
```

You can use it this way:

```
Map<String, Object> pars = new HashMap<>();
pars.put("name", "O'Really");
String sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME = :name";
```