# How to populate jComboBox using select statement and join table in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select, join

everyone.

I've got a little task to do but I'm a bit stuck, basically I have two tables in mySQL one called 'muscleGroup' and 'muscleExercise'. The first table is essentially a list of categories for different exercises containing two columns 'group_id' and 'groupName'. Than I'm having the exercise table, and as a foreign key I'm using the 'group_id' column from the 'muscleGroup' table.

What I'm trying do now is to have a 'muscleGroupComboBox' which contains the values of 'groupName' column, and than based on what you have selected I need to populate another comboBox with the exercises that belongs to this specific group of muscles.

Here is my method to populate the muscleGroup comboBox.

```
private void populateMuscleGroupComboBox() {
    String comboBoxQuery = "SELECT groupName FROM musclegroup";
    ResultSet rs;
    PreparedStatement statement;
    try {
        statement = con.prepareStatement(comboBoxQuery);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String groupName = rs.getString("groupName");
            groupComboBox1.addItem(groupName);
            groupComboBox2.addItem(groupName);
            groupComboBox3.addItem(groupName);
            groupComboBox4.addItem(groupName);
            groupComboBox5.addItem(groupName);
            groupComboBox6.addItem(groupName);

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

This is my second method to populate the exercise ComboBox.

```
private void populateExerciseComboBox(String group) {
    String comboBoxQuery = "SELECT muscleGroup.group_id, muscleGroup.groupName, muscleExercise.exerciseName FROM muscleGroup,muscleExercise WHERE muscleGroup.groupName =\"" + group + "\"";
    ResultSet rs;
    PreparedStatement statement;
    try {
        statement = con.prepareStatement(comboBoxQuery);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String exerciseName = rs.getString("muscleExercise.exerciseName");
            jComboBox7.addItem(exerciseName);

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
}
```

Here I call the methods

```
    populateMuscleGroupComboBox();
    populateExerciseComboBox(groupComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Now this kind of work but there is something wrong with my Select statement as it returns all the exercises from the exercise table, I know its to do with the WHERE clause but I'm not sure how to make it work.

```
   "SELECT muscleGroup.group_id, muscleGroup.groupName, muscleExercise.exerciseName FROM    muscleGroup,muscleExercise WHERE muscleGroup.groupName =\"" + group + "\"";
```

Help would be appriciated

Comment: I believe you're missing a quotation mark; `\"" + group...` should be `"\"" + group...`

Comment: No, that's not it. It's something to do with the logic of the select statement. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't restricting where muscleExercise and muscleGroup are the same group id... see the amended `WHERE` predicate below.

`"SELECT muscleGroup.group_id, muscleGroup.groupName, muscleExercise.exerciseName FROM    muscleGroup,muscleExercise WHERE muscleGroup.groupName =\"" + group + "\" and muscleExercise.group_id = muscleGroup.group_id";`

OR... (preferred)

```
SELECT  muscleGroup.group_id, muscleGroup.groupName, muscleExercise.exerciseName 
FROM    muscleGroup
JOIN    muscleExercise USING(group_id)
WHERE   muscleGroup.groupName =\"" + group + "\"
```

actually you should use prepared statements and parametrize group instead of just adding it in the query.
[How does Java's PreparedStatement work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419021/java-prepared-statement-arguments)

Comment: Yes the second solution works as I intended, thank you very much ;)