# A normal query close the connection between java and MySql

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I don't understand why when i'm try to execute a normal query created dynamic such this

```
INSERT INTO messaggio(Nickname,DataConnesione,DataMessaggio,messaggio) VALUES ('Anonymous','2017.06.11 20:56:02','2017.06.11 20:56:06','Hello!');
```

This query is created in this Java code:

```
QUERY = "INSERT INTO messaggio(Nickname,DataConnesione,DataMessaggio,messaggio) VALUES ('"+username+"','"+dateConnections+"','"+time+"','"+message+"');";
```

And when i try to execute this update

```
        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I have this exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1198)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1193)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4046)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4015)
    at Server$ClientThread.run(Server.java:289)
```

I post the full code because i don't really know what is the possible problem.

```
/*
 *  server constructor that receive the port to listen to for connection as parameter
 *  in console
 */
public Server(int port) {
    this(port, null);
}

public Server(int port, ServerGUI sg) {
    // GUI or not
    this.sg = sg;
    // the port
    this.port = port;
    // to display hh:mm:ss
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss");
    // ArrayList for the Client list
    al = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
}

public void start() {
    keepGoing = true;
    /* create socket server and wait for connection requests */
    try 
    {
        // the socket used by the server
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        // infinite loop to wait for connections
        while(keepGoing) 
        {
            // format message saying we are waiting
            display("Server waiting for Clients on port " + port + ".");

            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();      // accept connection
            // if I was asked to stop
            if(!keepGoing)
                break;
            ClientThread t = new ClientThread(socket);  // make a thread of it
            al.add(t);                                  // save it in the ArrayList
            t.start();
        }
        // I was asked to stop
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
            for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
                ClientThread tc = al.get(i);
                try {
                tc.sInput.close();
                tc.sOutput.close();
                tc.socket.close();
                }
                catch(IOException ioE) {
                    // not much I can do
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            display("Exception closing the server and clients: " + e);
        }
    }
    // something went bad
    catch (IOException e) {
        String msg = sdf.format(new Date()) + " Exception on new ServerSocket: " + e + "\n";
        display(msg);
    }
}       
/*
 * For the GUI to stop the server
 */
protected void stop() {
    keepGoing = false;
    // connect to myself as Client to exit statement 
    // Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    try {
        new Socket("localhost", port);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // nothing I can really do
    }
}
/*
 * Display an event (not a message) to the console or the GUI
 */
private void display(String msg) {
     String time = sdf.format(new Date()) + " " + msg;
    if(sg == null)
        System.out.println(time);
    else
        sg.appendEvent(time + "\n");
}
/*
 *  to broadcast a message to all Clients
 */
private synchronized void broadcast(String message) {
    // add HH:mm:ss and \n to the message
    time = sdf.format(new Date());
    String messageLf = time + " " + message + "\n";
    // display message on console or GUI
    if(sg == null)
        System.out.print(messageLf);
    else
        sg.appendRoom(messageLf);     // append in the room window

    // we loop in reverse order in case we would have to remove a Client
    // because it has disconnected
    for(int i = al.size(); --i >= 0;) {
        ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
        // try to write to the Client if it fails remove it from the list
        if(!ct.writeMsg(messageLf)) {
            al.remove(i);
            display("Disconnected Client " + ct.username + " removed from list.");
        }
    }
}

// for a client who logoff using the LOGOUT message
synchronized void remove(int id) {
    // scan the array list until we found the Id
    for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
        ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
        // found it
        if(ct.id == id) {
            al.remove(i);
            return;
        }
    }
}

/*
 *  To run as a console application just open a console window and: 
 * > java Server
 * > java Server portNumber
 * If the port number is not specified 1500 is used
 */ 
public static void main(String[] args)throws SQLException {
    try {       
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS );


        System.out.println("Connesione al DB effettuata");
    }catch( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
            if ( ps != null ) {
                ps.close();
            }
            if ( rs != null ) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if ( conn != null ) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }

    // start server on port 1500 unless a PortNumber is specified 
    int portNumber = 1500;
    switch(args.length) {
        case 1:
            try {
                portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid port number.");
                System.out.println("Usage is: > java Server [portNumber]");
                return;
            }
        case 0:
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Usage is: > java Server [portNumber]");
            return;

    }
    // create a server object and start it
    Server server = new Server(portNumber);
    server.start();
}

/** One instance of this thread will run for each client */
class ClientThread extends Thread {
    // the socket where to listen/talk
    Socket socket;
    ObjectInputStream sInput;
    ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
    // my unique id (easier for deconnection)
    int id;
    // the Username of the Client
    String username;
    // the only type of message a will receive
    ChatMessage cm;
    // the date I connect
    Date date;

    // Constructore
    ClientThread(Socket socket) {
        // a unique id
        id = ++uniqueId;
        this.socket = socket;
        /* Creating both Data Stream */
        System.out.println("Thread trying to create Object Input/Output Streams");
        try
        {
            // create output first
            sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            sInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            // read the username
            username = (String) sInput.readObject();
            display(username + " just connected.");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            display("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + e);
            return;
        }
        // have to catch ClassNotFoundException
        // but I read a String, I am sure it will work
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
        date = new Date();


    }

    // what will run forever
    public void run() {
        String QUERY = null;
        //Date when the user log
        String dateConnections=sdf.format(date);
        // to loop until LOGOUT
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        while(keepGoing) {
            // read a String (which is an object)
            try {
                cm = (ChatMessage) sInput.readObject();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                display(username + " Exception reading Streams: " + e);
                break;              
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                break;
            }
            // the messaage part of the ChatMessage
            String message = cm.getMessage();

            // Switch on the type of message receive
            switch(cm.getType()) {

            case ChatMessage.MESSAGE:
                broadcast(username + ": " + message);
                QUERY = "INSERT INTO messaggio(Nickname,DataConnesione,DataMessaggio,messaggio) VALUES ('"+username+"','"+dateConnections+"','"+time+"','"+message+"');";
                System.out.println(QUERY);
                try {
                    ps = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case ChatMessage.LOGOUT:
                display(username + " disconnected with a LOGOUT message.");
                keepGoing = false;
                break;
            case ChatMessage.WHOISIN:
                writeMsg("List of the users connected at " + sdf.format(new Date()) + "\n");
                // scan al the users connected
                for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
                    ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
                    writeMsg((i+1) + ") " + ct.username + " since " + ct.date);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        // remove myself from the arrayList containing the list of the
        // connected Clients
        remove(id);
        close();
    }

    // try to close everything
    private void close() {
        // try to close the connection
        try {
            if(sOutput != null) sOutput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
        try {
            if(sInput != null) sInput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {};
        try {
            if(socket != null) socket.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    /*
     * Write a String to the Client output stream
     */
    private boolean writeMsg(String msg) {
        // if Client is still connected send the message to it
        if(!socket.isConnected()) {
            close();
            return false;
        }
        // write the message to the stream
        try {
            sOutput.writeObject(msg);
        }
        // if an error occurs, do not abort just inform the user
        catch(IOException e) {
            display("Error sending message to " + username);
            display(e.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I use Eclipse Kepler and mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin
Thanks to all and sorry for my bad english, i'm very beginner to programming.

EDIT: I try to fill all on run() method:

```
        public void run() {
        String QUERY = null;
        //Date when the user log
        String dateConnections=sdf.format(date);
        // to loop until LOGOUT
        boolean keepGoing = true;
        while(keepGoing) {
            // read a String (which is an object)
            try {
                cm = (ChatMessage) sInput.readObject();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                display(username + " Exception reading Streams: " + e);
                break;              
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                break;
            }
            // the messaage part of the ChatMessage
            String message = cm.getMessage();

            // Switch on the type of message receive
            switch(cm.getType()) {

            case ChatMessage.MESSAGE:
                broadcast(username + ": " + message);
                try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS )) {
                    QUERY = "INSERT INTO messaggio(Nickname,DataConnesione,DataMessaggio,messaggio) VALUES ('"+username+"','"+dateConnections+"','"+time+"','"+message+"');";
                    System.out.println(QUERY);
                    ps = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    conn.close();
                    ps.close();
                    rs.close();

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
                break;
            case ChatMessage.LOGOUT:
                display(username + " disconnected with a LOGOUT message.");
                keepGoing = false;
                break;
            case ChatMessage.WHOISIN:
                writeMsg("List of the users connected at " + sdf.format(new Date()) + "\n");
                // scan al the users connected
                for(int i = 0; i < al.size(); ++i) {
                    ClientThread ct = al.get(i);
                    writeMsg((i+1) + ") " + ct.username + " since " + ct.date);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        // remove myself from the arrayList containing the list of the
        // connected Clients
        remove(id);
        close();
    }
```

But is not work:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Server$ClientThread.run(Server.java:274)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close your `Connection` right after obtaining it (in `finally` clause):

```
        if ( conn != null ) {
            conn.close();
        }
```

After you close it, you cannot use it anymore, that's why you get the exception.

The idiom you use here ('guaranteed close after use') usually looks like this:

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = ... // open connection
    doSomeWorkOnConnection(conn);
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

In this case the `Connection` is only closed after all the work on it has been finished (and work is only being done in `doSomeWorkOnConnection()` method). But in your case your `Connection` seems to be global (it's just an assumption as we don't see `conn` declaration), so it should be only closed in the very end of your program (and surely not right after the connection has been established).

By the way, there is a more modern form of the same idiom (try-with-resources):

```
try (final Connection conn = openConnection()) {
    doSomeWorkOnConnection(conn);
}
```

This will auto-close the `Connection` when `try` block will be left.

**How the problem may be fixed**

One way to solve it is to use `Connection` per client, then you could use try-with-resources idiom. But in this case you could have performance penalty (for connection initialization) if `Client` only lives for a short time. Alghouth, that penalty could be overcome with connection pooling.

Another way is to leave the `Connection` global for a `Server`. This means that you need to make it non-static, declare it in `Server` class (if it's not declared there) and init it in `Server` constructor (or initialization method). Then you could call `conn.close()` in some method that finishes `Server` lifetime (for example, in `stop()` method).

**Update on `PreparedStatement`**

Also, you don't use `PreparedStatement` in the way it is intended to be used. (For example, such concatenation makes you susceptible to SQL injection attacks.) The idea is to avoid that stringn concatenation and use placeholders to allow the driver/database to bind the actual query parameters.

So

```
// use placeholders in the query (marked with ? sign)
QUERY = "INSERT INTO messaggio(Nickname,DataConnesione,DataMessaggio,messaggio) VALUES (?,?,?,?);";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY);
// now bind the variables
ps.setString(1, username);
ps.setString(2, dateConnections);
ps.setString(3, time);
ps.setString(4, message);
// and only now execute the query
ps.executeUpdate();
```

More info: [How does Java's PreparedStatement work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419021/how-does-javas-preparedstatement-work)

Comment: So, can you pls tell me where i close the connection for can work there QUERY in there position?

Comment: When you use try-with-resources like this `try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS )) {` you don't need to close the `Connection` yourself as you do (`conn.close()`) as it will be closed in implicit `finally` block matching the `try` block.

Comment: About the `NullPointerException`, locate that line 274 and see what is the code there. This will help you to see what reference is `null`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it The idea is to find that

Comment: Also, added a section on `PreparedStatement`

Comment: I thank you heartily, now everything works perfectly.
I used your `try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection (DB_URL, USER, PASS)` and put all query operations in it (Although I'm not clear about this syntax, I would like to understand something ...) I also understood how to use `PreparedStatement ` .
Thank you again and sorry for my inexperience

Comment: You are welcome! No need to be sorry, we are all here to learn :) Some information on try-with-resources: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html