# Unknown column 'sunny' in where clause

Tags: java, jdbc

```
  <body>
    <%  String name=session.getAttribute("user").toString();    %>

 <br>

  <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
  <%
   try
  {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   java.sql.Connection 
   con=DriverManager.getConnection
   ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pbl","root","");
   Statement st=con.createStatement();
   String q="select pcode ,pname,pprice from car where us="+name;
   ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(q) ;
 %>
```

error:
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL 
    syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
    version for the right syntax to use near 'by name' at line 1

Comment: Paste the error log.

Comment: There has to be a clean dupetarget for this. If not, this can become the clean dupetarget.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419021/how-does-javas-preparedstatement-work ... but I won't close, because every query is different.

Answer (score 4):

> i guess the problem in this line String q="select pcode,pname,pprice from car where us="+name;

Yes, because the name (sunny, apparently) it isn't in SQL quotes, so it looks like a column reference.

**NEVER** use string concatenation to add values to SQL queries. Use [prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select pcode ,pname,pprice from car where us = ?");
ps.setString(1, name);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

That way, the information is handled as data, not as SQL (properly escaped if necessary, etc.). Things to notice there:

1. You use `?` where the values go. You *don't* put `?` in quotes or anything, even when you're going to use a string for the value.
2. You get a prepared statement by calling `prepareStatement` on the connection.
3. You **don't** pass a string into `executeQuery`. (This is important, because sadly you *can* pass a string into `executeQuery` on a `PreparedStatement`, which bypasses the whole point of using prepared statements; it should have been defined to cause an exception, but sadly it it wasn't.)

Let me introduce you to [my friend Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/):

[image: Her daughter is named Help I'm trapped in a driver's license factory.]

Comment: @TJCrowder Actually, when you pass a query string to `executeQuery` you are actually calling `Statement#executeQuery`, which is not a prepared statement method.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Right. That's why I said not to do that. (Because sadly, `PreparedStatement` doesn't override `executeQuery(String)` and throw an exception, as I believe it ought to have done.)