# SQL parameter issue Jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I am taking input from user and storing in two different variables. I am binding the parameters with my sql statement. When i run the code its giving issue on concatenating part of query.

```
String CityA= null;
String CityB= null;
try {
   CityA = readEntry(in, "Enter Origin City : ");
   CityB = readEntry(in, "Enter Destination City : ");

   // We treat this drop table specially to allow it to fail
   // as it will the very first time we run this program

  try {
  String q = "SELECT f.FLNO,f.DISTANCE,TIMEDIFF(f.arrives,f.departs) 
              as Duration FROM FLIGHTS F"
              + " WHERE F.ORIGIN = "+CityA;
              + "AND f.DESTINATION = "+CityB;

  System.out.println(q);
  rset = stmt.executeQuery(q);
  while (rset.next()) {
     System.out.println(rset.getInt("FLNO") + "," 
     + rset.getInt("Distance") + "," 
     + rset.getTime("Duration"));
  }
  System.out.println("Done");
  }
  catch (SQLException e) {
  // assume not there yet, so OK to continue
}        
finally {
        stmt.close(); 
}
```

Comment: `+CityA;` ? this completes a statement. You must review the entire code syntactically first.

Comment: @hassan please see my code

Comment: you code does not compile. And NEVER EVER get rid of exception, i'm pretty sure a simple `e.printStackTrace()` will give you the answer...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Java's PreparedStatement work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419021/how-does-javas-preparedstatement-work)

Comment: _"When i run the code its giving issue"_ please provide a more explicit and full description if your problems. And never ever use empty catch blocks. Your _"// assume not there yet, so OK to continue_" is an incorrect assumption. And you should never concatenate values into a query string, it is unsafe and prone to errors. Please learn about prepared statements and parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the code for query:-
Basically you missed the space between the `CityA` and `AND`

```
String q = "SELECT f.FLNO,f.DISTANCE,TIMEDIFF(f.arrives,f.departs) as Duration FROM FLIGHTS F"
                + " WHERE F.ORIGIN = '"+CityA+"' ";
                + "AND f.DESTINATION = '"+CityB+"'";
```

Comment: Although this may solve the immediate problem, it is unsafe as it is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your query string - you missed the space between `'Los-Angeles'` and `AND`.

Comment: no it's not the issue. issue is in query part where i am binding paramters city A and B with sql

Comment: More than this, you should surround the string with ``` char

Comment: Although this may solve the immediate problem, it is unsafe as it is vulnerable to SQL injection.