# %1$s throws exception in application.properties

Tags: java

I have this in my application.properties file and use that property in String.format in my code. If the format specifier is %s , it works. But for %d I am getting an exception 
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String

In application.properties I have

```
m.query = select * from table where name ='%1$s' and num=%d
```

In my code

public List retrieveDData(String source_name, String aclass, String service,
            String vdate, long start, long size) {

```
    log.info("test: "+config.getQuery());

    String t = String.format(config.getQuery(),aclass,

            start);

    log.info("test: "+ t);
```

How to fix the application.properties file so I wont get this exception? I realized 1$ is what is causing the exception . I have a big query. I need to reuse the parameters.

Thanks fro your time and help.

Comment: Unrelated, but: Your code contains an SQL injection vulnerability. You should never concatenate dynamic values into an SQL query.

Comment: Add to @meriton comment: you should use preparedstatement

Comment: `String name = 'Nam'` doesn't compile.

Comment: Edit your question and show us the code you’re actually running.  That imaginary code does not generate the exception you’re seeing (and, as Renato pointed out, doesn’t even compile).

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry everyone

Answer (score 1):

### Prepared Statements

You should not be doing this manually. It is better to use prepared statements which are easier and also much safer. They escape incoming values so that you won't be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Have a look @ [How does Java's PreparedStatement work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419021/how-does-javas-preparedstatement-work)

### Your error

I think the main clue is the following:

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
```

However, as pointed out in the comments, and verified by myself just now, there is no actual error in the code you provided.

I ran the following code (after correcting your errors), and everything works fine.
I also loaded the property file directly using `java.util.Properties`. Will see if going through spring changes this :

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]){


        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("test.properties")) {

            Properties prop = new Properties();

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

            // get the property value and print it out
            String test = prop.getProperty("query");
            System.out.println(test);

            String name = "NAME";
            long num = 10L;
            System.out.print(String.format(test,name,num));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “A long is a floating point number.”  No, it’s not.  A long is a 64-bit signed integer.  And [it’s perfectly legal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#dnint) to format a long with `%d`.

Comment: This is not exactly what reported into  [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#detail): %d is a valid option for all the following types: byte, Byte, short, Short, int and Integer, long, Long, and BigInteger

Comment: You guys are right. Also, his code (with a fix) works without throwing the specific exception.